# Multi-Line link animation on :before

Tags: css, animation

Like in the question, I have a code

How to make this effect work on many text lines and not as it is now - the effect appears only in 1 of e.g. 2 text lines (like example)

```css
:root {
--00a3a3: #00a3a3;
}

a {
position: relative;
text-decoration: none; /* For Example */
}

a:before {
content: "";
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 2px;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
background-color: var(--00a3a3);
visibility: hidden;
-webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
transform: scaleX(0);
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

a:hover:before {
visibility: visible;
-webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
transform: scaleX(1);
}
```

```html
<a href="#">test</a>
<br>
<br>
<a href="#">test
<br>
test2
</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the `::before`. Instead apply a `background-image` to the `<a>`.

```css
:root {
--00a3a3: #00a3a3;
}

a {
position: relative;
text-decoration: none; /* For Example */
background-image: linear-gradient(#00a3a3, #00a3a3);
background-position: 50% 100%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 0% 2px;
transition: background-size .3s;
}

a:hover {
background-size: 100% 2px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">test</a>
<br>
<br>
<a href="#">test
<br>
test2
</a>
```

**Edit:** 
The problem is that the `:before` pseudo-element doesn't know that your `<a>` is two lines. It's just adding a new block element inside it and taking the shape you give it.

If you know that your links will always be two lines, you might be able to get away with using an `:after` for the second line, like this:

```css
:root {
  --00a3a3: #00a3a3;
}

a {
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  /* For Example */
}

a:before,
a:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  left: 0;
  background-color: var(--00a3a3);
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
  transform: scaleX(0);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

a:before {
  bottom: 0;
}

a:after {
  bottom: 1em;
}

a:hover:before,
a:hover:after {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
  transform: scaleX(1);
}
```

```html
<a href="#">test</a>
<br>
<br>
<a href="#">test
<br>
test2
</a>
```

(But you're probably better off restructuring your code to remove the `:before`.)

Comment: I've got this effect on a few pages. I'm blocking it in some elements eg. `element a:before {visibility: hidden;}`. It would take a lot of time to completely rewrite the code, so my question is: would it be possible to do it on `visibility`?

Answer (score 2):

Use background combined with `box-decoration-break` to have a duplicated effect on each line

```css
:root {
  --00a3a3: #00a3a3;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  background:linear-gradient(var(--00a3a3),var(--00a3a3)) bottom center no-repeat;
  background-size:0% 2px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  /* Remove the below to see the diffrence */
  -webkit-box-decoration-break: clone;
  box-decoration-break: clone;
}

a:hover{
  background-size:100% 2px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">test</a>
<br>
<br>
<a href="#">test
<br>
test2
</a>
```